# leaflet polygon matrix incorrect ordering

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

hello everyone I have polygon matrix that displays on different map layers. When I am in tileLayer matrix shows over the map and bringToBack method works correct.But when I switch into the vectorLayers, vectorLayers comes over the polygon matrix and it shows incorrect.

```
vectorLayersSources: Record<string, L.GeoJSON> = {};

  tileLayersSources: Record<string, L.TileLayer> = {};

featureGroups = L.featureGroup();
```

this is my toggling function that works when i switch the layer into the vector mode.

```
  toggleVectorLayer = (layer: string, onOff: boolean) => {
    if (this.vectorLayersSources) {
      if (onOff) {
        if (!this.featureGroups.hasLayer(this.vectorLayersSources[layer])) {
          this.vectorLayersSources[layer]?.addTo(this.featureGroups).bringToBack();
        }
      } else {
        this.featureGroups.removeLayer(this.vectorLayersSources[layer]);
      }
    }
  };
```

this is my tile toggler function

```
 toggleTileLayer = (layer: string, onOff: boolean) => {
    if (this.tileLayersSources[layer] !== undefined) {
      if (onOff) {
        if (!this.featureGroups.hasLayer(this.tileLayersSources[layer])) {
          this.tileLayersSources[layer].addTo(this.featureGroups).bringToBack();
        } else {
          this.featureGroups.removeLayer(this.vectorLayersSources[layer]);
        }
      } else {
        this.featureGroups.removeLayer(this.vectorLayersSources[layer]);
      }
    }
  };
```

and this is my layer handling function that works in every render.

```
 handleLayerChange = (layer: string) => {
    const layerToActivate = this.vectorLayersSources[layer] || this.tileLayersSources[layer];
    if (layerToActivate !== undefined) {
      Object.values(this.vectorLayersSources).forEach((layerToRemove) => layerToRemove.remove());
      Object.values(this.tileLayersSources).forEach((layerToRemove) => layerToRemove.remove());
      layerToActivate.addTo(this.featureGroups).bringToBack();
    }
    if (layer === 'Nordic Vector') {
      this.toggleMinimap(false);
    } else {
      this.changeMinimapUrl(layer);
      this.toggleMinimap(true);
    }
  };
```

how can i fix this issue?

I tried to add new feature group for map update instead of adding vector or tile layers directly into the map but it doesn't seem work